# how to do many to many with the same table with EF4 Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, ef-code-first

I have this schema:

```
create table Person
(
id int identity primary key,
name nvarchar(30)
)

create table PersonPersons
(
PersonId references Person(id),
ChildPersonId references Person(id)
)
```

how to create the classes to map them using EF4 Code First CTP5 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework 4 CTP 5 Self Referencing Many-to-Many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981228/entity-framework-4-ctp-5-self-referencing-many-to-many)

Answer (score 10):

For the POCO...

```
class Person
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

...set up the mapping in the DbContext...

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasOptional(entity => entity.Parent)
            .WithMany(parent => parent.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(parent => parent.PersonId);
}
```

...will give you a default implementation.  If you need to rename the table explicitly (and want a many-to-many relationship), add in something like this...

```
class Person
{
    public Guid PersonId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Children { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ConfigureProducts(modelBuilder);
    ConfigureMembership(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasMany(entity => entity.Children)
        .WithMany(child => child.Parent)
        .Map(map =>
        {
            map.ToTable("PersonPersons");
            map.MapLeftKey(left => left.PersonId, "PersonId"); 
            map.MapRightKey(right => right.PersonId, "ChildPersonId");
            // For EF5, comment the two above lines and uncomment the two below lines.
            // map.MapLeftKey("PersonId");
            // map.MapRightKey("ChildPersonId");
        }); 
}
```

Comment: where do I connect the .Map( map => with everything else ?

Comment: edited above to show MTM configuration with .Map().  I imagine there might be a way to define both a Person and a PersonPersons POCO directly too.

Comment: Note: in EF 5.0, just change `map.MapLeftKey(left => left.PersonId, "PersonId");` to `map.MapLeftKey("PersonId");`, and do so for the right key.

Comment: I used this design and then I found out that the table will prevent you from deleting entities.  Brilliant.