# How to create many-to-many relationship on the same entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

For example I have `Poduct` entity:

```
public class Product : DatabaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    ...
}
```

**The idea is I want to create the editable collection of similar products for product. So it is like many-to-many but on the same entity - product** So I updated my model like below:

```
public class Product : DatabaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Product> SimilarProducts { get; private set; }
    public void AddSimilar(Product product)
    {
       SimilarProducts.Add(product);
    }

    ...
}
```

also I updated my `DbContext` class:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
                .HasMany(p => p.SimilarProducts)
                .WithOptional()
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

implemented edit product action:

```
public ActionResult Edit(ProductEditModel productEditModel)
{

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productEditModel.SelectedSimilarProductLinkName))
    {
         var similarProduct = _productRepository.GetProduct(productEditModel.SelectedSimilarProductId);
         product.AddSimilar(similarProduct);
     }
    _productRepository.AddProduct(product);
}
```

**void IProductRepository.AddProduct(Product product);**

```
public void AddProduct(Product product)
{
     _repository.InsertOrUpdate(product);
}
```

But I get strange results: To product was added `Product_Id` field in my database and there is no such as `ProductProduct` table or something like that which stores related products ids as in usual many to many entities implementations. How can I create this table manually? What am I missing or what am doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5102930/how-to-do-many-to-many-with-the-same-table-with-ef4-code-first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Swell for advice, I've already figured out the solution:

**Model:**

```
public class Product : DatabaseEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}

    public ICollection<Product> ParentSimilars { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> ChildSimilars { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public IEnumerable<Product> SimilarProducts
    {
        get
        {
           return ChildSimilars.Concat(ParentSimilars);
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

**DbContext setup**:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.ChildSimilars)
            .WithMany(p => p.ParentSimilars)
            .Map(m =>
                     {
                         m.MapLeftKey("Product_Id");
                         m.MapRightKey("SimilarProduct_Id");
                    });
```

That's, basically, all.