# POCO self referencing many to many

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

It is look like same question but mine little bit different.

[Entity Framework 4 CTP 5 Self Referencing Many-to-Many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981228/entity-framework-4-ctp-5-self-referencing-many-to-many)

sample code;

```
public class Category 
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Category> Parents { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }        
}
```

I got right result when I define a field Parent as Category, instead of parents as List.

Category class well designed, but POCO? What should I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What problem do you have exactly? And are you really still using CTP5? It's outdated and you should update to EF 4.1 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/04/11/ef-4-1-released.aspx)

Comment: Can a Category actually have *multiple* parents?

Comment: @Slauma: sorry EF 4.1, i have been changed question.

Comment: @Diego: yes. category have to multiple parents.

Comment: But what doesn't work? If I try your model with EF 4.1 I get many-to-many mapping with one single join table. I looks correct to me. I cannot see the problem.

Comment: How do you make this work with a single Parent?

Comment: @Yablargo it will be like this public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class works fine for me without any customizations. Even the `[Key]` attribute is not required.

Here's some code that exercises this model:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var parent1 = new Category { Name = "Parent 1" };
    var parent2 = new Category { Name = "Parent 2" };
    var child1 = new Category { Name = "Child 1" };
    var child2 = new Category { Name = "Child 2" };
    parent1.Children = new List<Category> { child1, child2 };
    parent2.Children = new List<Category> { child1, child2 };
    context.Categories.Add(parent1);
    context.Categories.Add(parent2);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var categories = context.Categories.OrderByDescending(x => x.Children.Count)
                                       .ToList();
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        Console.Write(category.Name + ": ");
        Console.WriteLine("Parents ({0}) Children ({1})",
            string.Join(",", category.Parents.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()),
            string.Join(",", category.Children.Select(x => x.Name).ToArray()));
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
Parent 1: Parents () Children (Child 1,Child 2)
Parent 2: Parents () Children (Child 1,Child 2)
Child 1: Parents (Parent 1,Parent 2) Children ()
Child 2: Parents (Parent 1,Parent 2) Children ()
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it is working. I made mistake when I checked Sql Server. I will never look at it again :)